# GPIO button wait for edge only works the first time

Tags: python, button, error-handling, raspberry-pi, gpio

I am using a raspberry pi with 2 buttons and an OLED screen for user interaction. This code works the first time through but as soon as I give a "negative" red button answer, and try to call the method over again, it no longer responds to any button push and I cannot break out of the code (have to hit the power button) so I know my error handling is also broken.

I've tried removing button events at the end of getanswer() and adding them on again in interaction() but it also doesn't work.

```py
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

#button 
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) 
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN) # Set pin to be an input pin and set initial value to be pulled low (off)
GPIO.setup(19, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN) # Set pin to be an input pin and set initial value to be pulled low (off)



def getanswer():
    GPIO.add_event_detect(19, GPIO.RISING, bouncetime=300)
    GPIO.add_event_detect(18, GPIO.RISING, bouncetime=300)
    while True:
        if GPIO.event_detected(19):
            print('yay')
            return 1
        if GPIO.event_detected(18):
            print('try again?')
            return 0
        time.sleep(.01)


def interaction():
    with canvas(device) as draw:
        draw.text((0, 0), 'Click the green', fill="white")
        draw.text((0, 12), 'button to begin!', fill="white")

    GPIO.wait_for_edge(19, GPIO.RISING, bouncetime=300)

    with canvas(device) as draw:
        draw.text((0, 0), 'ready?', fill="white")
    time.sleep(5)

    #dostuff

    with canvas(device) as draw:
        draw.rectangle((0,25,90,60), outline="white", fill=tup)
        draw.text((0, 0), 'Is this it?', fill="white")    

    ans = getanswer()
    if ans == 0:
        interaction()
    else:
        print('goodbye')


def main():
    interaction()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

I just want to loop through until the user pushes the green button in getanswer(). And probably add better error handling.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your button connections and button possitions, when you press button, how they change their status for example  it goes high to low, or low to high and check them with multimeter.Sometimes solder makes problem. After hardware control, you can look "https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Inputs/" and you can use other input function for your project.